# sk-learn classification probability or confidence

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there a way to get a classification model in sk-learn to output a confidence or probability for a prediction, instead of just the class (even if there are only two classes)?

Intuitively, there are samples which should be clearly attributed to one class, and other samples which would be borderline, and it might be useful to distinguish those for certain practical problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the sklearn docs for the classifiers, you will find that some of them have functions that are called something like `predict_proba()` (or `decision_function` like And mentioned for SVMs and other models like Logistic Regression). An example is in the RandomForestClassifier docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba). The probabilities for each class will be calculated in a way that depends on the specific model, but they should yield probabilities for each class for each sample you feed into it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Typically your model will provide a member function called `decision_function` which returns the distance of the given sample to the separating hyperplane which you can interpret as confidence.

Check out this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html#example-svm-plot-weighted-samples-py) for SVM classification for usage.